# What would cause server to URLRequest corruption

Tags: android, iphone, json, urlrequest

I have an app on iphone and android that both fail periodically when calling the server. When I say that they fail I mean that I get no errors codes, 200 Connection code meaning that it was successful, but a corrupted string/data/(jsonObject/Array). I list all of those data types because depending on the app they use some or all of them. The information when printed out in sting form does have the return JSON coming from the server, but it is corrupted with extra code or text that will not allow JSONParsers to work properly. Like I said before it doesn't fail all the time and it only fails in what is in the returned string/json/data. I have been told before that I am connecting, receiving, and handling the information correctly and that I should look to the server. We have changed servers in the middle of this and it works faster but still has a similar fail rate. Also, the server does not fail or have issues with browsers. So, in all web browsers it throws no errors, doesn't corrupt the site and or the information that is displayed. So, if I get on my computer and go to the website I will see the correct information every time when I load the page. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your server log its responses? Look in the log to see if the server's response is the same as what the mobile devices are receiving.

Comment: That is something that I will try, thank you. I am assuming if they are the same then there is something wrong server side and if they are not the same then there is something wrong devise side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I found out for android was that it was the old server, but the new serve still had issues with the IOS app but I figured out that if you alloc the NSString with the NSData then the information will not have any possiblities of gaining extra data or information. So alloc works.